# Juntar diferentes filas en una sola matriz

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente problema, he formado 4 filas que quiero juntarlas y que formen parte de una matriz. En este caso, la primera variable será la primera fila, la segunda variable será la segunda fila, la tercera variable será la tercera fila y la cuarta variable será la cuarta fila.

```
fil_cat1<-matrix(c(inf_cat1), nrow = 1, ncol = 496)
fil_cat2<-matrix(c(inf_cat2), nrow = 1, ncol = 496)
fil_cat3<-matrix(c(inf_cat3), nrow = 1, ncol = 496)
fil_cat4<-matrix(c(inf_cat4), nrow = 1, ncol = 496)
```

En este caso, fil_cat1 será la primera fila, fil_cat2 será la segunda fila, y así sucesivamente. ¿Alguien se le ocurre alguna manera de juntarlo todo en una misma matriz?, y que sea una matriz única.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes [`rbind()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cbind) y [`cbind()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cbind) para "juntar" vectores por filas o columnas, por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
rbind(fil_cat1, fil_cat2, fil_cat3, fil_cat4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución. A la hora de crear la matriz, al final ponemos byrow=TRUE, entonces nos colocará los datos por filas.

```
Ysetc <- matrix(c(inf_cat1, inf_cat2, inf_cat3, inf_cat4), nrow = 4, ncol = 496, byrow = TRUE)
```

De esta manera saldrá los datos colocados en la matriz por filas.